# Why (Num a, Ord a) => a

Tags: haskell

I have following type signature:

```
let kessel :: (Ord a, Num b) => a -> b -> a; kessel = undefined
```

When I asked for result type:

```
:t kessel 1 2
```

I've got:

```
kessel 1 2 :: (Num a, Ord a) => a
```

Why not `Integer`?

Comment: It will be `Integer` if you assure the compiler that the first argument is an `Integer`, not an `Int` `Double` etc. So `:t kessel (1::Integer) 2` is `Integer`

Comment: Why do I not get just `Num` instead of `(Num a, Ord a) => a`

Comment: Only the first argument matters. It must be `Ord` because you required that. It must be `Num` because you used a numeric literal.

Comment: That in the signature for `kessel` you used `Num b` as a constraint on the second argument, is not affecting the type here.

Comment: But how it can becomes `Num a`  instead of `Num b`?

Comment: The type of the second argument of `kessel` doesn't affect the type of the result, which is the same as that of the first argument. Maybe it would be clearer if you actually implemented eg. `kessel a b = a` with your signature. What's making `kessel 1 2` just some Num+Ord or other is that `1` is some Num or other.

Comment: Note, e.g. that `kessel 'a' 2 :: Char`

Comment: @zero_coding I think you misunderstand what `Num a => a` means. The `a` is just an arbitrary label, not related to the `a` or `b` in your original type signature. It could just as easily be `Num foo => foo`, but we usually use one letter by convention. `Num` on it's own is not a type, it's a _constraint_ on a generic type, and we need to give that generic type a local name, in order to constrain it and refer to it in other parts of a type. The syntax just means: _Any type (let's call it `a`) that is constrained by the `Num` type class_.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `1` has type `Num a => a`:

```
ghci> :t 1
1 :: Num a => a
ghci> :t kessel
kessel :: (Num b, Ord a) => a -> b -> a
ghci> :t kessel 1
kessel 1 :: (Num a, Num b, Ord a) => b -> a
ghci> :t kessel 1 2
kessel 1 2 :: (Num a, Ord a) => a
```

The constraints from `1` (`Num`) get *added* to the already existing ones. It's the same when you use `id` for example:

```
id   :: a -> a
id 1 :: Num a => a
```

## Longer explanation

When you use `kessel :: (Ord a, Num b) => a -> (b -> a)`, you tell the compiler that `kessel` will take *any* `a`, that is an instance of `Ord`. `kessel` will then return a function from *any* other (not necessarily different) type `b`, that is also an instance of `Num` to the previously mentioned type `a`.

This means that the first argument you use for `kessel` will set `a`:

```
ghci> :t kessel (1 :: Int)
kessel (1 :: Int) :: Num b => b -> Int
ghci> :t kessel 'A'
kessel 'A' :: Num b => b -> Char
ghci> :t kessel "Hello, World!"
kessel "Hello, World!" :: Num b => b -> String
```

In all these cases, the type of the argument was clear. But what if we use a value that is polymorphic? For example this one:

```
magic :: Magic a => a
```

And also let's use a simpler function, namely `const`:

```
const :: a -> b -> a
const x y = x
```

What is `const magic`? Let's start simpler. What is `const "Hello, World?"`?

```
const                 :: a      -> b -> a
"Hello, World?"       :: String
const "Hello, World?" ::           b -> String
```

We replaced *every* occurence of `a` with `"Hello, World?"`'s type. Now back to our `magic` example:

```
const       ::            a -> b -> a
magic       :: Magic t => t
const magic :: Magic t =>      b -> t
```

Again, we replace every occurrence of `a` with our type, in this case `t`. However, we must not forget the additional constraint on `t`, namely `Magic`. We must bring it along. Therefore, we gain the additional constraint here. But if there were any constraint on `a`, we still have to place them to `t`.

Let us now go back to your original `kessel`:

```
kessel   :: (Num b, Ord a         ) => a -> b -> a
1        :: (Num n                ) => n
kessel 1 :: (Num na, Ord na, Num b) =>      b -> na
```

We *still* keep `a`'s original constraint. Therefore, we now have two constraints, `Num` and `Ord`. If we now use any type that fulfilfs the `Num` constraint, all we have left is `na`. Since it is not on the right hand side anymore, its constraint can be discarded:

```
kessel 1 2 :: (Num na, Ord na) => na
```

Comment: How can I read `kessel 1 :: (Num a, Num b, Ord a) => b -> a` ?  Why can I eliminate `b` here `kessel 1 2 :: (Num a, Ord a) => a`? I can not eliminate `a` here `kessel 1 2 :: (Num a, Ord a) => a`, because is still bound?

Comment: The result of `id 1 :: Num a => a` would be an instance of `Num`? What is a Context inheritance from class(the operator `=>` ) mean?

Comment: You can eliminate `a` in `kessel 1 2 :: (Num a, Ord a) => a` by telling the compiler exactly what you mean by `1`, e.g. `kessel (1::Integer) 2 :: Integer` As it stands a numeric literal can be in any numeric type `a`, which is what `Num a => ...` means.

Comment: @Zeta It looks like a lambda calculus beta reduction right?